# Make countdown in background task on ios react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, countdown

Right now I have this in my componentDidMount() methode:

```
setInterval(() => this.getTimeUntil(getTheTimeToAdd, count++), 1000);
```

It calls another methode for updating every second to count down. I have a problem when the user is counting down the application might close or the iPhone goes to sleep.

I have tried to use both:

```
react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation
```

and:

```
react-native-background-timer
```

To keep the count down running even when the iPhone sleeps og the application is closed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create new Dates for each invocation to see the elapsed time. Like

```
setInterval(function() {
  Date d = new Date();
  if (this.oldDate && this.oldDate.getTime() + DELAY_THRESHHOLD < d.getTime()) {
    ...
    this.oldDate = d;
  }
  else {
    ... //should anything be here?
  }
},500);
```

Comment: The count down is working it's the background task on the iPhone that dosent. If I close the app and do something else and open the app again the timer is still the same. It have to count in the background.

Comment: @MaikenMadsen if you keep the start date in some sort of storage and count from that time if the app closes or restarts you can count the remaining time again because you have the start time as date.

Comment: I have det count down as a number. example that it will count down from 15 min so the number is: getTheTimeToAdd = 15*60. It will be 900 seconds.

Comment: @MaikenMadsen Ok that's good. So if you store the start date somewhere, you just need to set the DELAY_THRESHHOLD value in the example above to `15*60*1000` milliseconds

Comment: I's still not working by placing 15*60*1000 inside the DELAY_THRESHHOLD variable value :-S

Comment: @MaikenMadsen I don't know what else to tell you

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using [`react-native-background-timer`](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer#react-native-background-timer),
you can use the `setInterval` from the `BackgroundTimer` instance.

Assuming that you've linked the project correctly, you should be able to do

```
// In the constructor or the state
this.state = {
            initialCounter: 120000, //Equivalents to 2 minutes
            active: false, // To show or hide a label
        }

componentWillMount() {
        this.setIntervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
            if (this.state.initialCounter === 0) {
                this.setState({
                    initialCounter: this.state.initialCounter,
                    active: true,
                })
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    initialCounter: this.state.initialCounter - 1000,
                    active: false,
                })
            }
        }, 1000)
    }

// Make sure to unmount the listener when component unmounts
componentWillUnmount() {
        BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(this.setIntervalId)
    }

// Helper func to reinitiate the counter
_onUpdate = () => {
        this.setState({ initialCounter: 120000, active: false })
    }

// And inside your render you may display the timer by formatting with moment()
```

*The docs are a bit misleading, since `setInterval` and `clearInterval` works on IOS too*. Tested on package **2.0.1**

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in iOS this way. Also using 2.0.1. Sent the app to the background and the interval stopped

Comment: Not sure, need to check the code for that. You can add it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should catch up every time the app wakes up.

```
const duration = 15; // duration in minute
const alertAt = Date.now() + duration * 60 * 1000;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const remaining = alertAt - Date.now();
    if (remaining < 0) {
        // time is up
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }
    console.log(remaining);
}, 10)
```